# Reformat python script with mix of tabspace in vim

Tags: vim, indentation

I have a python script that's been formatted such that some places have `tabstop=3`, whereas others have the same variable set to `2/4`. Is there a way in vim to reformat the script and make `tabspace=4` all throughout?

Here's a sample of what my script looks like.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
def foo():
   # tabspace=3
   x = 1
   y = 2
   z = 3

def bar():
    # tabspace=4
    z = 0
    for i in range(10):
        z = i + z
    return z

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # tabspace=2
  foo()
  bar()
```

Comment: The easy way to do it is to use [autopep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8/).  It does more than fix the spacing though.

Comment: @SatoKatsura thanks for the tip. I did use autopep8 but was wondering if there's a nice vim tip for such tasks

Comment: I don't think there is such an internal tip; in my view, to make it without an external tool, you would have to write a function parsing the indentation for each line, and acting in consequence. But autopep8 seems to be possible to use inside vim like a filter, something like this: `:%!autopep8 -`